# Idle redo shortcut vanished

Tags: python, python-idle

I have Python versions 3.2, 3.3.2, and 3.3.4, and when using Idle for 3.3.4, my redo shortcut doesn't work properly, but there are no issues with Idle for 3.2 or 3.3.2. In 3.3.4 when I try `command-shift-z` (I'm using Mac-Lion), I get undo, instead of redo. However, if I open the Edit menu, and then try `command-shift-z`, redo works properly. Is there any reason why this would occur, or a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug triggered by use of current versions of the Cocoa Tk 8.5, such as the current ActiveTcl 8.5.15.  I've opened [an IDLE issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21359) to investigate.

Comment: That may explain it. I got ActiveTcl 8.5.15 to handle the warning that 3.3.2 would display.

Comment: Alas, the story of Tk support on OS X is a pretty sad one.  All in all, you're better off using the latest 8.5.15 as older versions have even more serious problems.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, would you know if 8.5.15 is responsible for butchering some widgets? I've got optionmenus that have the menu floating halfway down the screen instead of anchored to the menu button.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  You could try temporarily moving the ActiveTcl out of the way and trying with the Apple-supplied Tk. `cd /Library/Frameworks; sudo mv Tcl.frameworks Tcl.disabled; sudo mv Tk.frameworks Tk.disabled`